# "L'obiettivo era questi quadri" o "L'obiettivo erano questi quadri"?

Tags: verbs

Ricordo di aver letto in un libro la frase "L'obiettivo era questi quadri" e di aver subito avuto l'impressione che non suonasse bene; se fossi stato al posto dell'autore, avrei probabilmente scritto "L'obiettivo erano questi quadri".

Credo che siamo d'accordo che il significato generale della frase non cambi da una versione all'altra: si parla in entrambi i casi di qualcuno che ha questi quadri come obiettivo.

La domanda diventa quindi: se doveste costruire la frase "l'obiettivo + (verbo essere) + questi quadri", scegliereste "era" o "erano"? Ovvero, a priori, quale scegliereste come soggetto della frase, "obiettivo" o "quadri"? (Non rispondete che "obiettivo" è soggetto perché l'autore del libro ha usato "era" e non "erano").

Le due possibilità sono supportate dalle seguenti motivazioni:

- L'autore sceglie "obiettivo" come soggetto perché si trova in prima posizione nella frase;
- Io sceglierei "quadri" come soggetto perché è dei quadri che si specifica una proprietà (quella di essere l'obiettivo).

Mi rendo conto che la questione è abbastanza soggettiva e non penso si possa arrivare ad una risposta definitiva, ma mi piacerebbe sentire che cosa pensate in merito.

Quale delle due versioni vi convince di più?

Comment: Il soggetto in questo contesto è "questi quadri".  Secondo me la prima versione è sbagliata

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti In base a cosa dici che "questi quadri" è il soggetto? Come faresti invece l'analisi logica di "questi quadri erano l'obiettivo" (o "era", che mi suona malissimo), e se la risposta è diversa perché?

Comment: La domanda è interessante, ma per come funzionano i siti StackExchange non sono incoraggiate domande che portano a esprimere opinioni personali. Piuttosto che chiedere che cosa ci “convince di più”, sarebbe meglio cercare qualcosa di più oggettivo: una regola, esempi d'autore etc.

Comment: Penso che entrambe le forme siano corrette perché, secondo [questo sito web](http://dico.unime.it/otrs/public.pl?Action=PublicFAQZoom;ItemID=21;ZoomBackLink=QWN0aW9uPVB1YmxpY0ZBUVNlYXJjaDtTdWJhY3Rpb249U2VhcmNoO0tleXdvcmQ9ZTtTb3J0Qnk9%0ARkFRSUQ7T3JkZXI9RG93bjtTdGFydEhpdD0x%0A;), in italiano il verbo "essere" può essere accordato tanto con il soggetto ("l'obiettivo") come con la parte nominale del predicato nominale ("questi quadri").

Answer (score 2):

Io mi concentrerei sull'*obiettivo* dell'obiettivo, e cioè su *questi quadri*, optando per "l'obiettivo erano questi quadri".

Comment: Può darsi, ma perché?

Comment: @DaG, ho solo espresso un'opinione, secondo la richiesta dell'autore del post: tra le due forme la seconda è quella che ho sentito più frequentemente (e che perciò mi suona meglio), ma non credo che la prima sia grammaticalmente scorretta. Lo è?

Comment: Hai ragione, forse è la domanda che non è impostata nel migliore dei modi.

Comment: Anche a me "l'obbiettivo erano questi quadri" *quadrerebbe* di più. :) Scusate ma non resistevo.

Answer (score 0):

Penso che la risposta sia da cercare nel contesto di quella frase.
Presa singolarmente opterei anche io per `"l'obbiettivo erano questi quadri"`.

In un contesto in cui potrebbe essere il soggetto o si volesse mettere in risalto l'obbiettivo, come ad esempio una frase simile a `"Il ladro aveva un solo obbiettivo, l'obbiettivo era questi quadri"`, potrebbe anche andare bene.